# Sonar violation except some method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, equals, sonarqube, hashcode

I want to exclude some methods from sonar (for analysis purpose).

Actually the auto-generated `equals()` and `hashCode()`. There are not using curly braces etc. and I don't always want to fix them. Are there any means to exclude the scope only for certain methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to the Switch Off Violations plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin.

You cannot set exclusions on methods but on blocks of code.
With "Block exclusion patterns":

- Regular expression for start of block = public int hashCode()
- Regular expression for end of block =  }